# C++ Split sequential code into multiple files

Tags: c++, header, microcontroller

I am writing a code for a microcontroller which has a very long main with many sequential instructions.

For management and development purposes I would like to divide the code into multiple files.

I would like not to create void functions with code inside as my microcontroller has a very small stack.

Is it possible to create some sort of header file with code inside that can be referenced by a single "instruction" in the main, such that once the code is compiled the instructions are effectively sequential and there are no extra function calls?

Thank you

Comment: Yes you can create a header file that can be "referenced" with a normal `#include` directive. Think about what `#include` *does*. However, it can make maintenance pretty nightmarish. Also, just one level of functions calls with only a few arguments and few to none local variables will not use much stack at all. Remember that 30 years ago having e.g. 4 kilobytes of stack was plenty for all kinds of code, including recursion and many levels of function calls. And 40 years ago less than one single kilobyte was still plenty.

Comment: if you really need. You can use inline modificatory for functions. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @BartekKaczor Note that `inline` is only a *hint* to the compiler, it might disregard it. Then the function also have to be defined in the same [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), so can't be in another source file.